# angularJS testing factories, returning undefined after get() - async issue

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am new to both angular and TDD and I'm looking for some help with one of my tests. The application I am making talks to an API backend, I have mocked this backend with some js fixtures.

json data:

```
{
"count": 25,
"total_count": 32,
"current_page": 1,
"per_page": 25,
"pages": 2,
"products": [
    {"name": "test"},
    {},
    {},
    {},
]}
```

Each of the products have a number of data I am only outlining the structure above.

My Passing test (jasmine)

```
'use strict';

describe('productsController', function() {

    var scope, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sprangularApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject( function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
        //Actual API 0.0.0.0:3000/api/, below is mock data only.
        var api_root = '0.0.0.0:3000/api/'

        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        //Get mock jsons
        jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath='base/js/tests/api_mock';

        $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products').respond(
            getJSONFixture('products.json')
        );

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('productsController', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    //Start Tests
    it('Should fetch all products', function() {
        // $httpBackend.flush();
        // expect(scope.products[5].name).toBe('Ruby on Rails Baseball Jersey');
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.products.count).toBe(25);

        expect(scope.products.products[0].id).toBe(1);
        expect(scope.products.products[0].name).toBe('Ruby on Rails Tote');

        expect(scope.products.products[9].id).toBe(5);
        expect(scope.products.products[9].permalink).toBe('ruby-on-rails-ringer-t-shirt');
    });
});
```

controller:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
 (function() {
var sprangularServices;

sprangularServices = angular.module('sprangularServices', ['ngResource']);

sprangularServices.factory('Defaults', function() {
  return {
    api_url: "0.0.0.0:3000/api/"
  };
});

sprangularServices.factory('Product', function($resource, Defaults) {
  var Product;
  return Product = (function() {
    function Product() {
      this.service = $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products/:id', {
        id: '@id'
      });
    }

    Product.prototype.create = function(attrs) {
      new this.service({
        product: attrs
      }).$save(function(product) {
        return attrs.id = product.id;
      });
      return attrs;
    };

    Product.all = function() {
      var data, service;
      service = $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products');
      data = service.get();
    };

    return Product;

  })();
});

 }).call(this);
```

Tests:

```
'use strict';

describe('productsController', function() {

    var scope, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sprangularApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject( function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
        //Actual API 0.0.0.0:3000/api/, below is mock data only.
        var api_root = '0.0.0.0:3000/api/'

        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        //Get mock jsons
        jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath='base/js/tests/api_mock';

        $httpBackend.when('GET', api_root + 'products').respond(
            getJSONFixture('products.json')
        );

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('productsController', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    //Start Tests
    it('Should fetch all products', function() {
        // $httpBackend.flush();
        // expect(scope.products[5].name).toBe('Ruby on Rails Baseball Jersey');
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.products.count).toBe(25);

        expect(scope.products.products[0].id).toBe(1);
        expect(scope.products.products[0].name).toBe('Ruby on Rails Tote');

        expect(scope.products.products[9].id).toBe(5);
        expect(scope.products.products[9].permalink).toBe('ruby-on-rails-ringer-t-shirt');
    });
});
```

The above code works fine and the test passes with flying colors. What I would like to do however is have Product.all return the products array within the JS without the meta information like product count etc.

I modified the service so that it would return:

```
  Product.all = function() {
    var data, service;
    service = $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products');
    data = service.get();
    return data.products
  };
```

It seems data.products is undefined, as is data, I have a feeling this could have something to do with flush, but I am not sure, why doesn't data.products return the array that is contained within the JSON? is it to do with get()'s synchronosity.

Comment: To anyone getting undefined on `getJSONFixtures`, it is bundled inside jasmine-jquery https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a synchronous issue.

Does this do what you want?

```
Product.all = function() {
  var data, service;
  service = $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products');
  return service.get().$promise.then(function (result) {
    return result.products;
  });
};
```

**EDIT**

If all you're doing is putting the result of `Product.all` on the `$scope` then you can (untested) do this:

```
Product.all = function() {
  var data, service;
  var products = [];
  service = $resource(Defaults.api_url + 'products');
  service.get().$promise.then(function (result) {
    for (var i in result.products) {
      products.push(result.products[i]);
    }
  });
  return products;
};
```

If you wish to do something else I'd do (untested):

```
$scope.$watch(Product.all, function (value) {
  $scope.products = value;
  // other stuff here to products
}/* , true */); // You probably need to deeply watch the array for changes - I can't test it at the moment.
```

Comment: I was actually in the process of writing something similar, this is exactly what I had in mind. That said however, after using your exact code I'm still getting undefined. It definitely was a synchonous issue because console.log was returning the get after another console.log written after it...any ideas why i'm still getting the error?

Comment: Seems the controller calls the $scope.products =, variable assignment before the data is retrieved, perhaps I have to move the logic following get to the controller..

Comment: Well to use the promise in the controller you'll need to wrap the assignment in the result of the promise.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah I think so, I guess I was hoping I could just have Products.all() in the controller (as you can in rails) without any other logic because it's a just looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: Hmm well I tried my best with my edit just now.  Check it out.